# How do I add history/reverse_matching feature to windows prompt?

Tags: windows, linux, prompt

In linux prompt,we can type `!mysql` and so on to match a history command to save time.

Is there a utility for windows(XP to be exact) that enables this feature?

Comment: The Windows Console actually has a "history", accessible with Up/Down and F7, and usable in most command-line programs (not just `cmd.exe`). Unfortunately it doesn't have `!` and other advanced features.

Comment: have you tried powershell?

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you should install GIt-bash on windows and you can do everything you would want to do without tweaking the bad-daemon.
Link to git-bash download: http://code.google.com/p/msysgit/downloads/list

Comment: I'm almost certain `git-bash` will be using [Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/), which would be what the question'er is after (rather than something primarily intended just for `git`)

Comment: Yes, I want to do it in the windows command prompt, so it's not this one.

Comment: Even though it's primarily intended just for git, it has this bash features which can be installed (and you can skip installing the git engine). But anyway, sure no point if it doesn't fit your exact criteria.

Answer (score 1):

Try typing `mysql` then press <kbd>F8</kbd>.

It searches history backwards for anything starting with `mysql`.  Multiple presses keep searching backwards, like <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> in `bash`.

It uses a feature called DOSKey, that used to be an optional extra in the DOS days, but it's been standard in `cmd` since Windows XP (and maybe NT).

[DOSKey reference](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/doskey.mspx?mfr=true).